# Topological basis of infinite product

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be the infinite product of the space $\{0,1\}$, where $\{0,1\}$ has the discrete topology and $X$ the product topology.
Let $A(a_0,...,a_n)=\{(x_n)\in X:x_0=a_0,...,x_n=a_n\}$ for $a_0,...,a_n\in \{0,1\}$.

> How do I prove that these sets $A(a_0,...,a_n)$ form a basis for the product topology on $X$?

**What I thought:**
Per definition $$\{U\times\{0,1\} \times\{0,1\}\times...|U\text{ open in}\{0,1\}\}\cup\{\{0,1\} \times V\times\{0,1\}\times...|V\text{ open in}\{0,1\}\}\cup...$$
is a subbasis of the product topology. That means that the set of finite intersections of elements herein form a basis. But all these finite intersections are exactly of the form of $A(a_0,..,a_n)$.
Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: No, it is not. These interesections are not of the form $A=A(a_0, \ldots, a_n)$. Let's start with the fact that $A$ is not open, it is closed (if I undestand it correctly). That's because it is a preimage of the projection $\pi^{-1}(a_0,\ldots,a_n)$. So one way to show that $\{A\}$ is a closed basis is by showing that $\{X\backslash A\}$ is an open basis. Which should not be that difficult.

Comment: @freakish How would I do that? I find it hard to see what open actually means in an infinite product

Comment: @freakish Isn't $A$ clopen?

Comment: Hmm, it might be. I will think about it more later and I'll get back to you.,

Comment: @freakish Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote my own answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2195349/4280): a base for the product $X = \prod_{i=1}^\infty X_i$ are all sets of the form 
$$\prod_{i=0}^n U_i \times \prod_{i=n+1}^\infty X_i$$

where all $U_i$ are open in $X_i$.
Now for $X_i = \{0,1\}$ the only non-empty and non-$X_i$ open sets are of the form
$\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ and picking a product with $U_i = \{a_i\}$ is the same as demanding $x_i = a_i$
So then when $U_i = \{a_i\}, a_i =0,1$:

$$\prod_{i=0}^n U_i \times \prod_{i=n+1}^\infty X_i = \{(x_i)_i \in X: x_0 = a_0,\ldots,x_n = a_n\}$$

So your question is a special case of this more general fact.

A direct proof an be given as well:

Suppose $p = (p_i) \in O$ where $O$ is product open. All sets of the form $p_n^{-1}[V_n]$, where $V_n \subset \{0,1\}$ is open, form a subbase as you rightly state. If we we take $V_n = \emptyset$ we get $\emptyset$, or $V_n =\{0,1\}$ we get the whole product, so we can assume that $V_n = \{0\}$ or $V_n = \{1\}$, for every non-trivial subbasic set. The finite intersections of subbasic elements form a base, so we have $n_0, \ldots, n_k \in \mathbb{N}$ (in increasing order) and $i_0,\ldots i_k \in \{0,1\}$ such that:

$$p \in \bigcap_{j=0}^k p_{n_j}^{-1}[\{i_j\}] \subset O$$

But then certainly:

$p \in A:= \{(x_i) \in X: x_0 = q_0, x_1 = q_1,\ldots x_{n_k} = q_{n_k}\}$

where $q_i = i_{n_j}$ if $i = n_j \in \{n_0, \ldots ,n_k\}$ and $q_i = p_i$ otherwise. And this set lies inside $\bigcap_{j=0}^k p_{n_j}^{-1}[\{i_j\}]$ by definition (and so $p \in A \subset O$). So sets like $A$ (fixed start sets) form a base for the product topology.

Comment: But what if one of the $U_i$ is $X$? Then the product is not of the form of an $A$.

Comment: @MichaelBendis we only need a base so we can assume all $U_i$ are not $X_i$, otherwise write the set as a union of 2.

Comment: What do you mean by union of 2?

Comment: @MichaelBendis Suppose that $U_0 = \{0,1\}$ then the let hand set is just the union of $\{(x_i): x_0 = 0, x_1 =a_1, x_n = a_n\}$ and $\{(x_i): x_0=1 ,x_1=a_1,\ldots a_n\}$, and so these sets still form a base

Comment: But dont you want the left hand set to be exactly of the form of $A$ and not a union of two?

Comment: @MichaelBendis I added a more direct proof, (messy notation though).

Comment: @MichaelBendis if we can write all basic sets as a union of "more basic" (fixed start sequence) sets, the latter also form a base.