# Basis of product topology

Tags: general-topology

Why are typical basis elements of a countably infinite product topology of $\prod_{i=1}^\infty X_i$ of the form
$$\prod_{i=1}^n U_i\times \prod_{i=n+1}^\infty X_i?$$
where of course the $U_i$ are open in the corresponding $X_i$.

Everywhere I look, it says that this is easy to see. Sadly, I just don't see it and I hope someone can help me out.

Edit: The definition of product topology that I use says that for $X\times Y$ it has as subbasis $\{U\times Y\}\cup \{X\times V\}$ with $U,V$ opens in $X,Y$ resp.

Comment: This (or something very similar) is typically the definition of the product topology. What definition are you using?

Comment: @MeesdeVries My definition is that $X\times Y$ has subbasis $\{U\times Y\}\cup \{X\times V\}$ with $U,V$ opens

Comment: @BillyBob This definition only works for finite products. You cannot apply it to the infinite case. In general the topology on $\prod X_i$ is given by sets of the form $\prod U_i$ where each $U_i$ is open in $X_i$ and $U_i=X_i$ for almost all (i.e. except for finitely many) $i$.

Comment: @BillyBob, you can generalize that definition to this case; a sub-basis is given by the sets which have the following form: the product of a $U_i \subseteq X_i$ on coordinate $i$, and the full space $X_j$ on all other coordinates. Does that help?

Comment: Notice the typographical difference between $\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^\infty X_i$ and $\displaystyle \Pi_{i=1}^\infty X_i.$ The former is standard usage and I edited accordingly.

Comment: This is called the Tychonoff product topology. There are others, such as the box product topology and the uniform ( or uniform convergence) topology.

Comment: @freakish I think it would be less ambiguous to use the word 'generated' rather than 'given'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X = \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_n$, then a subbase for this topology is given, as for any product, by all sets of the form $[n,U]:= (\pi_n)^{-1}[U]$, where $ n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $U$ is open in $X_n$, which we could also denote (slightly less acurately, abusing notation a bit) as

$$[n,U] = \prod_{m < n} X_m \times U \times \prod_{m > n} X_m$$

So we have a set that is only not the whole space for one coordinate $n$, where it equals $U$ instead.

Now the *finite* intersections of all subbasic elements always form a base for the topology that is generated  by the subbase.

Now, note that

$$\prod_{i=1}^n U_i \times \prod_{i= n+1}^\infty X_i = \bigcap_{i=1}^n[ i,U_i] $$

so these sets are all in the base.

And if we have any finite intersection of subbasic elements, say $[i, U_i], i \in F$, where $F \subset \mathbb{N}$ is finite, then set $n = \max(F)$, 
and for $i \le n$ define $V_i = U_i$ if $i \in F$ and $V_i = X_i$ otherwise, now all $V_i$ are open in $X_i$, and

$$\bigcap_{i \in F} [i, U_i] = \prod_{i=1}^n V_i \times \prod_{i=n+1}^\infty X_i$$

is also of the right form; we just "stuff"" with $X_i$ and finite sets have a maximum, so beyond that we always get $X_i$.

So all sets of the prescribed form are exactly all finite intersections of subbasic elements, so a base for the product topology.

Comment: Note that if $V_i = X_i$ is a problem, we can always use non-trivial open sets of $X_i$ ,if they exist, to write these sets as a union of "all non-trivial start" open sets.